# Adicionar 1 Produto a 2 Carrinhos simultaneamente WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

É possível adicionar 1 produto em 2 carrinhos (de 2 e-commerces do WooCommerce) ao mesmo tempo?

Ou seja, tenho um produto e estou direcionando ele para “https://loja1.meudominio.com.br/loja-virtual/?add-to-cart=856” e então o produto é adicionado ao carrinho da LOJA 1. Porém tenho uma Loja 2 também, e não sei como fazer esse direcionamento para as duas lojas simultaneamente.

Comment: e se fizer uma requisicao ajax para a loja 2 e assim que terminar voce redireciona da loja 1 como ja esta fazendo.

Comment: Como poderia fazer essa requisição ajax pelo WP Neurer? Não utilizo ajax quase nunca.

Comment: Como o WP usa o jquery pode seguir a [documentacao](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do proprio e tambem o bom e velho [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) do WP.